# Nothing displays from XML/XSLT and CSS

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I have an XML page (www.shiningpixel.co.uk/databaseconnect.php) that uses XSL and CSS to style it. Currently, nothing shows and I cannot see what is going wrong. Any ideas?

***XSL page:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy速 -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xmlstyle.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2>Your traces</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Users/Person">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Firstname"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Lastname"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Username"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>


    <table>
  <xsl:for-each select="Users/Person">
    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="Firstname"/></td></tr>

    <tr><td colspan="9"><hr size="1" width="100%" /></td></tr>

    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="Username"/></td></tr>

</table></br></br>



  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***CSS Page:***
This is /xmlstyle.css and is located in the same root folder as the xml and xslt file from above.

```
      body { background-image:url('bg.png'); }

      body {

  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

  padding: 100px;

  font-size: 13px;

}


table {

  background: #fff;

  margin: 0 auto;

  width: 600px;

  padding: 15px; 

  text-align: center;

  /* border-radius */

  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

  -moz-border-radius: 5px;

  border-radius: 5px;

  /* box-shadow */

  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;

  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;

  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;

}



hr 

{  

border:none;    

border-top:1px #CCCCCC solid;

height: 1px;

WIDTH: 80%;

}



<hr>



}
```

Comment: Is the path correct CSS?, copy and paste in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Well the browser (or at least Firefox) tells you there is a problem with the stylesheet:

```
XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </xsl:for-each>.
Location: http://www.shiningpixel.co.uk/style.xsl
Line Number 40, Column 3:</table></br></br>
--^
```

You have not closed the second `<xsl:for-each select="Users/Person">` at all.

Comment: Okay. I've closed that off, but the problem still remains.

Comment: When I visit the page now it displays a table filled with data: `Your traces
First name Last name Username
Ash Beardmore Username4
Name4 LName4 Username4
Joey Tester Username4
Form test Username4
fgafga htqehqher Username4
fgafga htqehqher Username4
hjvjh jjglg Username4
hjvjh jjglg Username4
hjvjh jjglg Username4
jkv j Username4
1 2 Username4`

Comment: I have reverted to an older version that worked, and use the sample code from W3Schools. It's not the layout I want, but I could not get it to work my way.